# Scrape table element by row name using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is the html that I want to **scrape**:

```
<dl class="some class">
    <dt> <strong>Text1</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result1</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text2</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result2</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text3</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result3</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text4</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result4</dd>
    .  .  .
</dl>
```

What I want is to get the `Result3` right next to `Text3`. In selenium, I would do this by:

```
parent=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("dl.BuyingOptions-labeledValues")
elem=parent.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(.,'Text3')]/following::dd[1]")
```

I want to use beautifulsoup for the same thing now. I first tried:

```
parent=soup.find("dl","BuyingOptions-labeledValues")
```

which is working fine and `print(parent.text)` gets all the table text. Then I tried:

```
elem = parent.find("dt",string='Country Of Origin')
```

This is not working. Please can someone help. I am new to beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS Selector with bs4 4.7.1+ `dt:contains("Text3") + dd`. This will select `<dd>` that is places immediately after `<dt>` that contains text `"Text3"`:

```
data = '''
<dl class="some class">
    <dt> <strong>Text1</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result1</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text2</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result2</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text3</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result3</dd>
    <dt> <strong>Text4</strong></dt>
    <dd> Result4</dd>
</dl>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

print( soup.select_one('dt:contains("Text3") + dd').get_text(strip=True) )
```

Prints:

```
Result3
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

---

Another method (using bs4 filtering):

```
print( soup.find(lambda t: t.name=='dt' and t.text.strip()=='Text3').find_next_sibling() )
```

Prints:

```
<dd> Result3</dd>
```